# Get range of records based on key - Aerospike

Tags: node.js, aerospike, nosql

I'm fairly new to Aerospike. Been checking the API docs, but I'm having trouble getting a clear process. I'm using the Node Client.

I have records:
Ex:

key: `{ns:'cache', set:'fieldA', key:'1437777737287'}`

value: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I want to make a query that will fetch records with matching ns, set 
and keys from 1437777737277 to 1437777737297, for example.

What would be the best approach ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [query with range filters](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/nodejs/usage/query/query.html):

```js
var filter = aerospike.filter;
var query = client.query('cache', 'fieldA', {filters: [filter.range('id', 1437777737277, 1437777737297)]});

var queryStream = query.execute();
queryStream.on('data', function (rec) {
  console.log(rec);
});

queryStream.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

queryStream.on('end', function () {
  console.log('the end')
});
```

Comment: That works as long as there's a secondary index built on a redundant bin called 'id' which holds the same value as exists in the primary.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [batchGet](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-nodejs/blob/master/docs/client.md#batchGet) to fetch a predefined range of keys, as log as the namespace and set are the same.